# how can i color titlebar in mfc in winc

Tags: mfc, windows-ce

i am trying to change color of titlebar but as onncpaint is not supported by winc what to do to color non client area like title bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try (but I don't know about WinCE so I'm not sure this will work) to enlarge the main window so that the title bar is outside of the screen, and then draw your custom title bar in the client area of the main window.